# How To Stop Reloading ViewController after First Launch

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Is there any way to stop reloading view controller, even the button of push segue have been clicked? Due to the view controller might have some program processing and it might takes time, and i don't want to reload that view again and restart the program again when the user clicked navigated to that view.

Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: What takes so long loading the controller? If you're accessing data remotely, then you ought to cache it outside the controller (persistent store, CoreData or other), and just refresh periodically or on request by the user rather than every time the controller gets loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any code that needs to run only when the app is launched can be put in `appDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:`.

If you have code that needs to be run as set up code only the first very time the app is launched and then never run again so long as the app remains installed on the device, you can still use `appDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:`, but you'll need to put some logic in to determine whether or not the app has been launched before.  The easiest way of accomplishing that looks something like this:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"previouslyLaunched"]) {
    // app already launched
} else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES 
        forKey:@"previouslyLaunched"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    // This is the first launch ever
}
```

Edit: You could apply the above code snippet to individual view controllers as well.

---

But as a note, the `viewDidLoad` method of a view controller is not necessarily called every time the view is presented.  Once `viewDidLoad` is called and the view is put onto the navigation stack, `viewDidLoad` won't be called again unless the view is removed from the navigation stack and then needed to be put back on the navigation stack.

For example, when using a navigation controller, the first time the first view is presented, the `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidAppear` methods are all called.  When you navigate to the next view in the navigation controller, then go back to the first view, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` will be called again, but `viewDidLoad` will not be called again.